# Android Development ImageButton Layering

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I am developing an application where I need a diagram of the human body where you can click on specific parts (chest, arms, legs, etc). I have separate pngs for each of the body parts so I'm hoping to create imageButtons and combine them but layouting them is turning out to be a mess. How would you guys approach putting these pngs together into an interactive body diagram where you can click any body part.

Comment: this may help you https://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/

Comment: Could you be more specific, as to how the layout is turning up a mess.

Comment: So as of right now, I am having a really hard time placing the individual images so that they look good in appearance when making the body diagram. The layout is not allowing me to place the pieces so that they fit nicely. I could use padding but that would mess up with different devices.

Comment: The first comment is actually exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `ImageButton` you can use an `ImageView` like the example below:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="yourOnClickMethod"
        android:src="@drawable/your_body_part" />
```

Using an `ImageButton` will add custom borders and effects you can find on an usual `Button`, I believe that's not what you seek.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

ImageButton is not really the way to go here.  Android views are all rectangular  and you generally only arrange them relative to reach others' edges. That's probably why you're having trouble laying things out.

What would be better is if you made a custom view that was responsible for positioning and drawing all the parts in a single view.  Then you have a click handler for that view that translates the click coordinates to body parts as you have knowingly arranged them.

Kind of a pain, but it really is the best way, IMO and you will get the most precision with the least trouble overall.  There are lots of great tutorials out there on how to make a custom view and draw its contents to a Canvas.